# Json.Net deserialize JSON objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've popped consuming a WebServer returning the Json bellow, and I'm not able to convert it to an object.

#### Json

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":{
        "24486146360":{
            "rfid":"123465789456",
            "products":[
            {
                "sale_id":35,
                "quantity":2,
                "price":"1",
                "total":"2",
                "unit":"uni",
                "sku":14
            },
            {
                "sale_id":36,
                "quantity":2,
                "price":"2.5",
                "total":"5",
                "unit":"uni",
                "sku":17
            }
            ]
        },
        "24758345953":{
            "rfid":"2129",
            "products":[
            {
                "sale_id":39,
                "quantity":1,
                "price":"10",
                "total":"10",
                "unit":"ml",
                "sku":19998
            }
            ]
        },
        "64577015900":{
            "rfid":"1934",
            "products":[
            {
                "sale_id":40,
                "quantity":1,
                "price":"10",
                "total":"10",
                "unit":"ml",
                "sku":19998
            }
            ]
        },
        "56768990934":{
            "rfid":"1746",
            "products":[
            {
                "sale_id":46,
                "quantity":1,
                "price":"8.00",
                "total":"8",
                "unit":"UN",
                "sku":20
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I used json2sharp to generate a class from the JSON, I then cleaned up the class and was left with the following:

#### My Class create help for json2sharp

```
public class Consumo
{
    public string rfid { get; set; }
    public List<ConsumoProduto> products { get; set; }
}

public class ConsumoProduto
{
    public int sale_id { get; set; }
    public double quantity { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public int sku { get; set; }
}

public class RetornoConsumo
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Processado { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Consumo> Registro { get; set; }
}
```

#### My Problem

how do I convert Json to a valid object using Json.Net?

#### Test

I tried to do this and I could not

```
Dictionary<string, RetornoConsumo> _featuredArticles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, RetornoConsumo>>(json);
```

Comment: Here the answer to your question: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

You wrote that you tried something and did not manage. What was the error?

Comment: Hi, your JSON structure features a dictionary for your "data" child. If you want C# to correctly deserialize the object, try making your json in the following structure: "data": [ { ...object values ...}, { another object} ]

Comment: You should try something like RetornoConsumo _featuredArticles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetornoConsumo>(json);

Comment: Copy Json content -> go to Visual studio -> Create new c# class File -> Edit menu -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as classes...  Job done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RetornoConsumo` class, the `Registro` property needs to be a `Dictionary<string, Consumo>` not a `List<Consumo>`.

```
public class RetornoConsumo
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Processado { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, Consumo> Registro { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you need to deserialize the JSON into the `RetornoConsumo` class:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetornoConsumo>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vfhdXp